# i am getting an error in adding a menu item to a menu

Tags: java, menu, awt, menuitem, reserved-words

```
import java.awt.*;

class Menu{
        Frame f;
        MenuBar mb;
        Menu m1,m2,m3;
        MenuItem mn1,mn2,mn3,mn4,mn5,mn6;

        Menu() { 
         f=new Frame();
         mb=new MenuBar();
         m1=new Menu();
         m3=new Menu();
         m2=new Menu();
         mn1=new MenuItem("new");
         mn2=new MenuItem("new");
         mn3=new MenuItem("new");
         mn4=new MenuItem("new");
         mn5=new MenuItem("new");
         mn6=new MenuItem("new");
         m1.add(mn1);
         m1.add(mn2);
         m2.add(mn3);
         m2.add(mn4);
         m3.add(mn5);
         m3.add(mn6);
         mb.add(m1);
         mb.add(m2);
         mb.add(m3);
         f.setMenuBar(mb);
         f.setTitle("menu demo");
         f.setVisible(true);
         f.setSize(300,300);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args){
           new Menu();
        }
    }
```

Comment: First rule of programming: read the error message.

Comment: Second rule of programming: read. (books, that is)

Comment: Which is the error you have? Can you add the stacktrace ofthe exception?

Comment: Third rule of programming: try something when the code goes wrong, check ur logics and dry run on paper

Comment: Please use a easy readable source, if you have a problem do not fill the whole code with useless menuitems, menus and so on. A simple [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a conflict there with the name `Menu`. You need to import the proper classes.Use

```
java.awt.Menu m1=new java.awt.Menu();
```

if you want to go with your class name as `Menu` or else change your class name to some other name and import a Menu class.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm. I think your class name is in conflict with the `Menu` you'd like to use...

No errors with an other name.

Answer (score 2):

Change the name of your class `Menu` to some other name, it is conflicting with `java.awt.Menu` class